Certain games cause monitor to be disabled when launching in exclusive fullscreen
Certain games (mainly Source games and Minecraft) that run in exclusive fullscreen causes my right monitor to be disabled and also often crashing the game in the process. I've tried 3 different distros (Fedora, EndevourOS, and now Linux Mint) and 3 DE's (KDE, XFCE, Cinnamon) and they all exhibit this behavior.
I've tried using both the 535 and 545 drivers, and turning on Force Full Composition Pipeline in my NVIDIA settings.
I'm running Linux Mint 21.3, an NVIDIA RTX 2060 12GB model from MSI and a i7 10700. Left monitor is a LG 24GN50W 1080p 144hz, and right is HP X27q 1440p 165hz
